# How to make ToolBar and StatusBar Gradient

Tags: gradient, android-toolbar, android-statusbar

how can I make ToolBar and StatusBar Gradient as shown image1 [This one I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAgfs.png) but I'm getting StatusBar and ToolBar as image2 [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z44vM.png). If you observed in 1st image the ToolBar is full gradient at endColor position(bottom of the ToolBar) but 2nd image of the ToolBar is not full Gradient as 1st image at bottom of the ToolBar and showing as a straight line. My code is as given below:

@drawable:

> toolbar_product_gradient.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient android:type="linear"
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#44000000"
        android:centerColor="#22000000"
        android:endColor="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```

> AppBarLayout with ToolBar

```js
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="@null"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_product_gradient" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarProduct"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
      app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:titleEnabled="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Please help me how to get it and thanks in advance.